# when I do the "saveUser" function with bcrypt in password postman send me "couldn't get any response"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, cygwin, postman

I get the "error" "Could not get any response" in postman when I try to test my POST of user: /register, this is my user-controller code, when I added the bcrypt for hash password, this is what I call in my user.js (controller):

```
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');
var User = require('../models/user');
var jwt = require('../services/jwt');
```

and this is the function where I want to get the POST

```
function saveUser(req, res){
    var user = new User();

    var params = req.body;

    console.log(params);

    user.name = params.name;
    user.surname = params.surname;
    user.email = params.email;
    user.role = 'ROLE_USER';
    user.image = 'null';

    if(params.password){
        // Encriptar contraseña
        bcrypt.hash(params.password, null, null, function(err, hash){
            user.password = hash;

            if(user.name != null && user.surname != null && user.email != null){
                // Guarda el usuario
                user.save((err, userStored) => {
                    if(err){
                        res.status(500).send({message: 'Error al guardar el usuario'});
                    }else{
                        if(!userStored){
                            res.status(404).send({message: 'Noseha registrado el usuario'});
                        }else{
                            res.status(200).send({user: userStored});
                        }
                    }
                });
            }else{
                res.status(200).send({message: 'Rellena todos los campos'});
            }
        });
    }else{
        res.status(200).send({message: 'Introduce la contraseña'});
    }
}
```

and I'm exporting that with:

```
module.exports = {
    saveUser
};
```

I have done the route in my folder routes:

```
var express = require('express');
var UserController = require('../controllers/user');

var api = express.Router();

api.post('/register', UserController.saveUser);

module.exports = api;
```

and my model is:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var UserSchema = Schema({
    name: String,
    surname: String,
    email: String,
    password: String,
    role: String,
    image: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

so I had everything but the app doesn't run, in my cygwin terminal it put me the response like but it dont save because the function "saveUser" doesn't work, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the solution, I delete the mongoose latest version and installed the 4.10.8

in cygwin:

```
npm install mongoose@4.10.8 --save
```